# Strapi send email to all administrators

Tags: strapi

Let's say we have a contact form connected with Strapi backend. Every form submit creates a new model entry and everything's fine except we need to notify administrators about new form submission.
So in `api/message/model.js` we add a custom lifecycle method:

```
module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async afterCreate(result, data) {
      await strapi.plugins["email"].services.email.send({
        to: [/* Here a list of administrator email addresses should be. How to get it? */],
        from: "robot@strapi.io",
        subject: "New message from contact form",
        text: `
          Yay! We've got a new message.
          User's name: ${result.name}.
          Phone: ${result.phone}.
          Email: ${result.email}.
          Message: ${result.text}.

          You can also check it out in Messages section of admin area.
        `,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

But I don't understand how to get administrator email addresses.

I've tried to query admins data like

```
console.log(
  strapi.query("user"),
  strapi.query("administrator"),
  strapi.query("strapi_administrator")
);
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it.
The model name is `strapi::user`. So the whole lifecycle hook may look like

```
module.exports = {
  lifecycles: {
    async afterCreate(result, data) {
      const administrators = await strapi.query("strapi::user").find({
        isActive: true,
        blocked: false,
        "roles.code": "strapi-super-admin",
      });
      const emails = administrators.map((a) => a.email);
      await strapi.plugins["email"].services.email.send({
        to: emails,
        from: "robot@strapi.io",
        subject: "New message from contact form",
        text: `
          Yay! We've got a new message.
          User's name: ${result.name}.
          Phone: ${result.phone}.
          Email: ${result.email}.
          Message: ${result.text}.

          You can also check it out in Messages section of admin area.
        `,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Comment: Don't send `blocked: false` as parameter, now, all of them are null for admins, so it will breaks the function.